# Android WebView with ProgressDialog. How do I kill it?

Tags: android, webview, progressdialog

I've tried everything I know how to do to kill it. What I want it to do is load the webpage and then kill the ProgressDialog. How do?

```
package com.calebfultz.package;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Lists extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web);
        ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(Lists.this, "", 
                "Loading. Please wait...", true);
        // Create reference to UI elements
        webView  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://cfultz.tumblr.com");


        // workaround so that the default browser doesn't take over
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient()

        );

    }


    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to make your ProgressDialog variable as a member variable of the Lists class and in your shouldOverrideUrlLoading method, add the line

```
pd.dismiss();
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that and unfortunately that just kills the progress dialog instantly, instead of waiting for the page to load.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // Show your progress dialog here

           prDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading, please wait...", true);

       super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    }

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

          //Finish your progress dialog here


        if (prDialog.isShowing() || prDialog != null) {
            prDialog.dismiss();
        }

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can override the onPageFinished function in MyWebViewClient: you can dismiss the ProgressDialog in this function. Or you can override the onProgressChanged in MyWebChromeClient(extends WebChromeClient): when the progress is 100, you can dismiss the ProgressDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this code:

```
// the init state of progress dialog
mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Please wait for a moment...");               
// add a WebViewClient for WebView, which actually handles loading data from web
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    // load url
               public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                    }

                    // when finish loading page
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        if(mProgress.isShowing()) {
                            mProgress.dismiss();
                    }
                    }
                });
```

it is working fine for me.........enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        //start loading animation
            //loading is a ProgressBar type
        this.loading.setVisibility(0);
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
               if(progress >= 100) {
                   this.loading.setVisibility(8);
               } 
            }
        });
```